# Setting a background image

Tags: html, css

I would like to use the image 'CI.png' as a background image in the div class 'manager-checklist'.  The CI.png file is located in the folder 'images' at the same level as the current sheet in which I am making the reference.   I believe there is a syntax issue for I am getting an 'invalid property message'.

```
.manager-checklist{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 8px;
    width: inherit;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: lightgray;
    padding: 4px;
    background-image: ../images/CI.png; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-image`s should use `url('path/to/image.png')`, so like this: `url('../images/CI.png')`. The quotes around the path are optional.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much